# php sort array by sub-value

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, sorting

here is my array, I think i should be using usort but i have no idea how to get that working.

```
Array
(
    [javascript] => Array
        (
            [core] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [file] => /path/to/file.js
                            [weight] => 0
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [file] => /path/to/file2.js
                            [weight] => 1
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I would like to sort the index of core by the weight value, other files and weights will be added and sorted after also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
usort($array['javascript']['core'], function($a, $b) {
    return $a['weight'] - $b['weight'];
});
```

Comment: i needed to create an actual function instead of how you did it about but it worked perfectly, mind explaining what it is doing?

Comment: @user Yeah, sorry. The closure only works in PHP 5.3. Best thing to do is read the [usort manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php). It has a pretty good definition of how the comparison function is used.

Comment: Had to change this to $a->weight - $b->weight because I am using an object, but this is perfect, thanks.